# Sails.js find() date

Tags: node.js, sails.js

The following queries return an empty array although my database has records in the given date.

```
    Event.find({date: "2016-12-25"}).exec((err, holidays) => {
    console.log(holidays);
    }

let myDate = new Date(parameters.year,parameters.month,parameters.day);
  Event.find({date: myDate}).exec((err, holidays) => {
    console.log(holidays);
    }
```

Anything I'm missing?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

According to the [documentation](http://sailsjs.com/documentation/concepts/models-and-orm/query-language) you could do it like so:

```
Model.find({ date: { '=': new Date('2/7/2014') } })
```